# BarChart can be moved/dragged

Tags: codenameone

I noticed that the bars of a BarChart in an CodenameOne-App can be moved/dragged. This is not useful in my case because the BarChart is contained in an Tab-Element where the tabs can be changed with swiping. Often the bars are moved instead of changing the tab selection.

Do you have any idea how to prevent the bars from being moved?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ChartComponent` methods `setZoomEnabled(false)` and `setPanEnabled(false);`